# Facing error while connecting MediaManager service

Tags: media-manager

while connecting to Media Manager service, getting error -

> No Version of CardSpace service was found to be installed on the machine, please install CardSpace and retry the operation.

```
MediaManager2011ClientFactory factory = new MediaManager2011ClientFactory();
var accounts = GetAccounts(factory); //facing error at this line


public static ItemData[] GetAccounts(MediaManager2011ClientFactory factory)
    {
        var accounts = factory.Client.GetRootList(GetListResultLevel.Minimal);//facing error at this line
        //Log.Info("This user has access to the following accounts:");
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            //Log.Info(account.Name);
        }
        return accounts;
    }
```

---

Please let me know what I am missing here to connect MediaManager service.

Comment: Neetesh, could you share your app.config file please? Do you have a Secure Token Service (STS) already in place?

Comment: How are you connecting to Media Manager? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neetesh, please try connecting to SDL Media Manager using the Helper class provided here: http://philipmedcraft.blogspot.com.br/2017/03/connecting-to-sdl-media-manager.html

```
var mediaManagerClient = MediaManagerHelper.GetMediaManagerClient();
IEnumerable<ItemData> accountlist = mediaManager2011Client.GetRootList(GetListResultLevel.Minimal);
```